# Get taxonomy image for Toolset custom taxonomy through Toolset Views Shortcode

Tags: custom-taxonomy, shortcode, images, advanced-taxonomy-queries, views

I'm using Toolset Views to display a list of taxonomies. These taxonomies are under a custom Taxonomy that I created with Toolset Taxonomies. I then used the plugin Taxonomy Images to add the option to have an image related to a term. I'm using a flat hierachy (tags) if that have any impact.

What I'm trying to achieve is that in the Views Loop I want to display the image that I have added to the term.

#### Views Loop:

```
<wpv-loop>
      <img src="[sagaio-term-image size='thumbnail' id='[wpv-taxonomy-id]' output='url']" />
      <h4>[wpv-taxonomy-title]</h4>
</wpv-loop>
```

#### My shortcode code:

```
function get_taxonomy_image( $atts ) {

    $atts = shortcode_atts( array(
        'image_size' => 'thumbnail',
        'id' => '',
        'output' => ''
        ), $atts );

add_shortcode( 'sagaio-term-image', 'get_taxonomy_image' );
```

#### Question:

How do I get the attachment ID for the specified taxonomy and output the URL?

I have looked at `wp_get_attachment_image_src` but I don't know how to get the ID of the attachment...

Answer (score 0):

The following code is partialy taken from the plugin [Taxonomy Images](https://wordpress.org/plugins/taxonomy-images/) and it's working:

```
function get_taxonomy_image( $atts ) {

    $atts = shortcode_atts( array(
        'image_size' => 'thumbnail',
        'id' => '',
        ), $atts );


    if( ! empty( $atts['id'] ) ) {
        $term = get_term( $atts['id'] );

        $related_id = 0;
        if ( isset( $term->term_taxonomy_id ) ) {
            $related_id = (int) $term->term_taxonomy_id;
        }

        $attachment_id = 0;
        $associations = get_option( 'taxonomy_image_plugin' );
        if ( isset( $associations[ $related_id ] ) ) {
            $attachment_id = (int) $associations[ $related_id ];
        }

        $imgsrc = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $attachment_id, $atts['image_size'] );

        return $imgsrc[0];
    }

    return 'no-id-set';
}

add_shortcode( 'sagaio-term-image', 'get_taxonomy_image' );
```